# Nomenclature of a Benzopyran (Chromene) as a Substituent of an Aldehyde

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image]

I am currently writing a paper on the benzopyran above.
I am attempting to name the compound using IUPAC conventions. Because there is an aldehyde moiety, I suspect I will need to name the compound as a substituent of methanal (so 1-(substituent name)methanal). I could alternatively name the aldehyde as a formyl moiety, but this would not be following IUPAC priorities. Benzopyrans have the following locants (with the 2H indicating an extra hydrogen at the 2 position). So, because the aldehyde is at the 6th locant, the compound would be named 1-(XXXXX-6-yl)methanal. The substituents on the benzopyran are as follows

- 2,2-dimethyl
- 2,7-dimethoxy
- 8-(1-oxo-butyl)

By assembling the everything in order, I get: 
1-(5,7-dimethoxy-2,2-dimethyl-8-(1-oxo-butyl)-2H-1-benzopyran-6-yl)methanal

I am not sure whether or not I should have named this compound based on the aldehyde moiety since it would be so trivial to name it as a formyl substituent instead?

[image]

Comment: Based on this  http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.9053158.html?rid=bd0a0081-98c9-4f63-9096-4c7722547f57  I would say your compound is 2,2-Dimethyl-5,7-dimethoxy-8-(1-oxo-butyl)-2H- chromene-6-carbaldhehyde

Comment: I had forgotten to account for the fact that the aldehyde was attached to a cyclic moiety, so I see why my name seemed so unnecessarily complex!

Comment: @Waylander The preferred prefix for “1-oxobutyl” is “butanoyl”. And the systematic benzo name (here: “2H-1-benzopyran”) is the preferred IUPAC name for “chromene”.